# timidity: No instrument mapped to tone bank 0, no idea which one is missing

Tags: ubuntu, audio, midi

I am trying to play [this midi file](http://per.kentel.pagesperso-orange.fr/sons/marivonnig1.mid) downloaded from [here](http://per.kentel.pagesperso-orange.fr/marivonnig11.htm), but I get:

```
$ timidity --verbose marivonnig1\ \(1\).mid 
Requested buffer size 32768, fragment size 8192
ALSA pcm 'default' set buffer size 32768, period size 8192 bytes
Playing marivonnig1 (1).mid
MIDI file: marivonnig1 (1).mid
Format: 1  Tracks: 2  Divisions: 192
Sequence: Marivonnig
Text: By Traditionnel
Text: Generated by NoteWorthy Composer
Time signature: 2/4 24 clock 8 q.n.
Time signature: 3/4 24 clock 8 q.n.
Time signature: 2/4 24 clock 8 q.n.
Time signature: 3/4 24 clock 8 q.n.
Time signature: 2/4 24 clock 8 q.n.
Time signature: 3/4 24 clock 8 q.n.
Time signature: 2/4 24 clock 8 q.n.
Time signature: 3/4 24 clock 8 q.n.
Time signature: 2/4 24 clock 8 q.n.
Time signature: 3/4 24 clock 8 q.n.
Time signature: 2/4 24 clock 8 q.n.
Track name: Staff
364 supported events, 3413810 samples, time 1:17
No instrument mapped to tone bank 0, program 41 - this instrument will not be heard
No pre-resampling cache hit
```

and ***no sound at all***.

[One more link](http://per.kentel.pagesperso-orange.fr/marivonnig51.htm), a different melody for the same text.

For some midi files from that site, I hear some sound, but I still get the message *No instrument mapped to tone bank 0* -- *this instrument will not be heard* and I suspect that what I hear is not what I should hear.

Maybe it needs some soundfont, but it does not tell me which one.

**How do I hear the melody?**

Answer (score 16):

`timidity` is a midi-renderer, but it doesn't come with instrument definitions by itself.

it seems that you are missing some soundfonts (at least for program `41`). in order to fix this, you might want to install/enable another set of instruments. e.g. *fluid-GM* seems to be pretty complete. make sure to enable it, once you have it installed. something like the following should help (lines starting with `$` are commands to be executed; lines starting with `#` are mere comments):

```
 $ sudo apt-get install fluid-soundfont-gm
 # then edit your /etc/timidity/timidity.cfg to activate the new soundfont
 # (and deactivate the old ones), e.g.:
 $ sudo sed -e 's|^source|#source|' -e '$a source /etc/timidity/fluidr3_gm.cfg' -i /etc/timidity/timidity.cfg
 # restart timidity
 $ sudo /etc/init.d/timidity restart
 # and play your file
 $ timidity --verbose marivonnig1\ \(1\).mid
```

Comment: This works, but it seems like the instruments are mapped to different kinds, The midi [Random Trance Music Generator](http://anticulture.net/) does only sound correct with the standard `source /etc/timidity/freepats.cfg`

Answer (score 1):

### install eawpatches

timidity is using `freepats` as default, try installing `eawpatches` as alternative:

```
sudo su
echo "deb https://www.fbriere.net/debian stable misc" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/midi-fbriere.net.list
wget -q -O- 'https://www.fbriere.net/public_key.html' | sudo apt-key add -
wget -q -O- 'http://pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x96B4BF71E4D7FB01' | sudo apt-key add -
apt install eawpatches-package
make-eawpatches-package
chmod 777 ./eawpatches_12-10+local_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./eawpatches_12-10+local_all.deb
# then edit your /etc/timidity/timidity.cfg to activate the new soundfont
# (and deactivate the old ones) with:
sudo sed -e 's|^source|#source|' -e '$a source /etc/timidity/eawpatches.cfg' -i /etc/timidity/timidity.cfg
```

Source [Enable eawpatches midi soundfont as alternative to freepats](https://askubuntu.com/q/1130431/34298)